# How to concatenate a int variable and a string when the int counts up and down?

Tags: swift, uitableview, concatenation

I have a table view with a + and - button that increases and decreases a counterLabel with 1, and a label with the name of the cell. In another view controller I have a summaryLabel that should show the counter, and the name of the cell that is tapped on.
For instance if the user tappes the plussButton in the "Banana cell" twice, and the "Tomatoe cell" once, the summaryLabel should show:

2 Banana
1 Tomatoe

The best result I have managed, is like this:

1 Banana
2 Banana
1 Tomatoe

It adds a new line every time the plussButton is tapped.

I use a TabBarController

Here is the code for the plussButton in the Main View Controller

```
extension MainViewController: CountDelegate {
   func didTapPluss(cell: MenuCell) {
       let indexPath = menuTableView.indexPath(for: cell)!

       items[indexPath.row].counter += 1

       cell.counterLabel.text = "\(items[indexPath.row].counter)"

       if let tbc = self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController {
          let total = ("\(items[indexPath.row].counter)" + "\(staticList[indexPath.row].name)")
          tbc.sharedInfo.append(total)
       } 
    }
}
```

Summary View Controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   if let tbc = self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController {
       sumaryLabel.text = "\(tbc.sharedInfo.joined(separator: "\n"))"
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot keep total as strings.You have to keep that as structured data, that is *counts for every item*. Convert to string only when displaying. Once you convert it to string, you lose control over it.

Comment: Ok, could you please be so kind to help me out with a example? I'm still very new to this, and I'm kind of stuck here :)